# gradient colouring of multiple y values for one x value in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, gradient, scatter-plot, plotly-python

I have a dataframe that contains 96 rows by 24 columns. Each group of 24 rows represents a day and each column represents an hour (from another day). This dataframe is also available split into 4 separate df’s which can make it easier to plot.

I want to plot all 96 rows for each column but have them colored so I can distinguish between the different days, then within those days have them colored with a gradient representing the hours, so I can overlay them and get an idea of the hourly pattern for each day.

So far I have tried the following for one 24x24 dataframe, but this gives me a gradient in the x direction instead of the y, i.e all y-values are the same color for one x but then change color with increasing x-values.

```
list_1 = []
for i in range(1,25,1):
    list_1.append('MTU_'+str(i))

df_w = df_w.set_axis(list_1, axis='columns')
fig = px.scatter(df_w, x=df_w.index, y=df_w.columns, color = df_w.columns ,color_continuous_scale=["red", "orange", "yellow"]
                 title="Forecast distribution for 01/01/2023")

fig.show()
```

Furthermore, how would I add the other 3 dataframes to the same figure, add traces on a G.O in a loop? ? If I try to do the same thing with the 96x24 dataframe I get an error for mismatched lengths.

Answer (score 0):

I would use go.Scatter for the whole thing and add a trace per column. Then assign a custom color gradient per trace. You can pre-generate an array of 24 gradient definitions, and assign one to each column. if you want to match the range you could set cmin and cmax of each trace to max(np.hstack(df)) and min(np.hstack(df)).

To create an intuitive color map you could create them using HSL: change H based on day, and L based on hour for instance.